# Retrieve EventLog from Azure Role using wevtutil

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, event-log

I am trying to retrieve event logs from the azure webrole remotely
using the "wevtutil" command, though I keep receiving errors saying
something like below.

> The event query could not be opened. The RPC server is unavailable.

The command I am using looks like the one below.

```
wevtutil qe Application /r:some-web-role.cloudapp.net /u:admin /p:password /q:*[System[(Level=1)]]
```

Remote desktop is enabled for the webrole, but currently, there are 2 instances running, so I think I need to specify which instance you want to access, though I do not know how.

Should I specify the instance name after the hostname as below?

(*) {#instance_name#}

```
wevtutil qe Application /r:some-web-role.cloudapp.net:{#instance_name#} /u:admin /p:password /q:*[System[(Level=1)]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you are not using [Azure Diagnostics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/), which was built to perform precisely this type of data capture and persistence?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Neil.

Actually, the environment I'm trying to access is another team's in another country and the subscription is different.
They just gave me the RDP files to access and not the connection strings to the storage. I'm asking them currently for it, but it is kinda' taking time, so I've just wondered if I could by using wevtutil.
(There are many instances by the way)

Comment: RDP to Azure role instances uses port forwarding to provide access to each role instance. I believe random ports are used so you would need to know these for each role instance in order to remote in,

Comment: OK, so it's not a thing you can do it easily by command.
(You've got to look the port number for each instances)

I guess I'll just use the Azure Diagnostics.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil pointed out, Azure Diagnostics was built specifically for this.
However, if you need to use wevtutil, ensure that Windows Firewall is open on the instances for appropriate remote admin.  I haven't tested this myself, however

```
netsh firewall set service type=remoteadmin mode=enable
```

Comment: Thanks Igorek.

Since the environment is an integration environment, I do not want to change the firewall settings on my own judge.

(*) For the reasons for not using Azure Diagnostics, please refer to the comment on Neil's answer.

Anyway, I've tried the netsh command on the other environment and tried again, but I still get the same error mentioned in my question.

Shouldn't I be needing to specify which instance to look in the wevtutil?